# Searching for young adult "survival tale" involving plane crash, poison

Tags: identification-request

In the 1990's - between 1990 and 1993 (I don't remember the exact year), we had an assigned reader for English literature at school. This was South Africa (Cape Town) and it was a private school. It was a soft cover. The book had a short title.

The story was about a plane crash and the man who survives eventually finds the wreck, takes food from it (canned food), and gets poisoned from radiation (perhaps). The book traces how he has to survive after nearly dying. If I recall, he has to hunt for food/make sure he has supplies for the winter months etc.

It's one man (definitely an adult) and I don't remember the setting.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to LitSE. Thanks for submitting such a clear identification request. There's lots of great detail already, but if you haven't read it already, there are some more ideas on [this page](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info).

Comment: LibraryThing has a list here that might have candidates: https://www.librarything.com/list/561/all/Survival-plane-crash-childrens%25252Fyoung-adult-fiction